# Convert boundfield to hyperlink in asp.net?

Tags: hyperlink

I'd like to ask how to convert this to hyperlink?

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Product Name" ReadOnly="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx) should be fine for this. It will look something like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="MyUrl"
                    DataTextField="ProductName"
                    HeaderText="Product Name"
                    Target="_blank"
/>
```

where *MyUrl* is public property's name in DataSource containing hyperlink. It might be useful to format URL with *DataNavigateUrlFormatString* attribute, e.g.:

```
DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/display/something/form.aspx?ID={0}"
```

if you want to build more complex anchor's *href* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Example complete:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="COD_DISC" datanavigateurlformatstring="~\otherview.aspx?COD_DISC={0}"  DataTextField="NOM_DISC" HeaderText="Name Column" Target="_self"/>
```

then you get value with query string in 'otherview'. Example:

```
            if (Request.QueryString["COD_DISC"] != null)
            urlParamentro = Request.QueryString["COD_DISC"].ToString();
```